Problema para instalar pip, y no es el path
estoy tratando de instalar pip pero la consola no lo reconoce, he visto que el problema suele ser el path, pero ya revise y el path esta bien. Mi teoria es que en el archivo pip de python no viene como pip.exe, ¿como puedo corregirlo?

¿Cómo estás tratando de instalar pip? ¿Qué errores obtienes?
